Why can my Azure Function cannot read the environment variable defined in the Startup class?
I want to read the connection string defined in host.json in my Startup class.The problem is when running IConfiguration is always null !
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net8.0</TargetFramework>
    <AzureFunctionsVersion>v4</AzureFunctionsVersion>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <FrameworkReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.App" />
    <PackageReference Include="Azure.Storage.Queues" Version="12.18.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Extensions" Version="1.1.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker" Version="1.20.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Extensions.Http" Version="3.1.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Extensions.Http.AspNetCore" Version="1.2.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Sdk" Version="1.16.4" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.WorkerService" Version="2.22.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.ApplicationInsights" Version="1.1.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection" Version="8.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Newtonsoft.Json" Version="13.0.3" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <None Update="host.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
    <None Update="local.settings.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
      <CopyToPublishDirectory>Never</CopyToPublishDirectory>
    </None>
    <None Update="Properties\launchSettings.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Using Include="System.Threading.ExecutionContext" Alias="ExecutionContext" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Compile Update="Startup.cs">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>Never</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </Compile>
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>


This is Function1.csproj
using Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using System;
using System.Configuration;

[assembly: FunctionsStartup(typeof(MyNamespace.Startup))]

namespace MyNamespace
{
    public class Startup : FunctionsStartup
    {
        public override void Configure(IFunctionsHostBuilder builder)
        {
            var configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
                .AddJsonFile("host.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
                .AddEnvironmentVariables().Build();

            IConfiguration conf = configuration;

            builder.Services.AddSingleton(conf);
            builder.Services.AddHttpClient();
        }
    }
}


This is the Startup Class i defined for my dependency injection of the IConfiguration !
using FirstFunction.dto;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Text;
using Azure.Storage.Queues;
using Azure.Storage.Queues.Models;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using System.Reflection;

namespace FirstFunction
{
    public class Function1
    {
        private readonly ILogger<Function1> _logger;
        private readonly IConfiguration _configuration;
        private readonly HttpClient _httpClient;

        public Function1(ILogger<Function1> logger)
        {
            _logger = logger;
        }

        public Function1(ILogger<Function1> logger, IConfiguration configuration, HttpClient httpClient) : this(logger)
        {
            _configuration = configuration;
            _httpClient = httpClient;
        }

        [Function("Function1")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Run([HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "get", "post")] HttpRequest req)
        {
            #region Catch Error
            string requestBody = string.Empty;
            try
            {
                requestBody = await new StreamReader(req.Body).ReadToEndAsync();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                _logger.LogError($"Error reading request body: {ex.Message}");
                return new StatusCodeResult(StatusCodes.Status500InternalServerError);
            }
            #endregion

            string myConnectionString = _configuration["ConnectionStrings:QUEUE_CONNECTION_STRING"];

 return new  OkObjectResult("Data was sent to backend");
        }
    }
}


This is my azure Function method. The code is shortened

using Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;

var host = new HostBuilder()
    .ConfigureFunctionsWebApplication()
    .ConfigureServices(services =>
    {
        services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetryWorkerService();
        services.ConfigureFunctionsApplicationInsights();
    })
    .Build();

host.Run();




This was generated called Programm.cs
The error message is not so exact because of that i let it slide!
thank you for your help !

Are you using Isolated Model?

yes, i think i should

Can you provde your csproj

where do i find this?

https://i.imgur.com/PyNVvVt.png double click on Name of Function app you will get it

i did it! I hope it wil work

Posted an answer below @heyoka955.

In Isolated Model , Startup is not used, you have to use Program.cs and to get value from host.json use below code and I have followed SO-Thread:
Program.cs:
using Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;

var host = new HostBuilder()
    .ConfigureFunctionsWebApplication()
    .ConfigureServices(services =>
    {
        services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetryWorkerService();
        services.ConfigureFunctionsApplicationInsights();
    })
    .ConfigureAppConfiguration((context, test) =>
    {
        test.SetBasePath(context.HostingEnvironment.ContentRootPath)
          .AddJsonFile("host.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
          .AddEnvironmentVariables();
    })
    .Build();

host.Run();

Function1.cs:
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;

namespace FunctionApp200
{
    public class Function1
    {
        private readonly ILogger<Function1> _logger;
        private readonly IConfiguration ri_con;
        public Function1(ILogger<Function1> logger, IConfiguration config)
        {
            _logger = logger;
            ri_con = config;
        }a

        [Function("Function1")]
        public IActionResult Run([HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "get", "post")] HttpRequest req)
        {
            _logger.LogInformation("C# HTTP trigger function processed a request.");
            var rith = ri_con["Value"];
            Console.WriteLine(rith);
            return new OkObjectResult($"Hello Rithwik, value is {rith}");
        }
    }
}

host.json:
{
    "version": "2.0",
  "logging": {
    "applicationInsights": {
      "samplingSettings": {
        "isEnabled": true,
        "excludedTypes": "Request"
      },
      "enableLiveMetricsFilters": true
    }
  },
  "Value": "Rithwik"
}

Output:



this seems work but how can i access the variables from launchSettings.json instead host.json ?

Same, use local.settings.json in place of host.json in Program.cs , AddJsonFile("local.settings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)

no i meant launchSettings.json which lies in Property folder!

Type launchsettings and check in place of host.json in program.cs and con string will be kept in local.settings.json

con string becomes null then, i think it did not find the launch file!

AFAIK,Yes as it is not a part of Function app so you will not get and i have never heard of it..

okay where i can save then my connection strings in azure function for production?

In App settings(Environment variable section) of Function app in Portal or you can deploy function from local and set con string in local.settings.json, it will load into app setting in Porrtal

but if i choose apporach one, how can i access the variable on my code when the variable lies on azure?

It works, you should check Microsoft documents, there are so many,if you have any doubt then open a new question, community will help.

it worked than you very much !
